# Creating a faster perfect hash function for 6-byte strings

Tags: c, string, optimization, hash-function

I have 6-byte strings of the format `cccnnn` where `c` is a character A-Z (ASCII 65-90) and `n` a character 0-9 (ASCII 48-57). There is a total of 26<sup>3</sup> * 10<sup>3</sup> = 17,576,000 different combinations.

I want to create a perfect hash function that maps each string of this type to an integer index and I want it to be as fast as possible. The function does not have to be minimal, but the range can not be too large. Twice the number of combinations might be okay, but preferably not not more than that because each string will be mapped to a bit in a bit array that is already ~2MB.

The most obvious, and so far best, solution I can think of is to interpret the string as a number in base 26 and 10 and do the required multiplications and subtractions to arrive at an integer in the range [0, 17576000-1]:

```
inline word hash1(unsigned char *buffer) 
{
  return (((((word) buffer[0]  * 26 + buffer[1]) * 26 
                  + buffer[2]) * 10 + buffer[3]) * 10 
                  + buffer[4]) * 10 + buffer[5]  - 45700328;
}
```

Here `buffer[0-5]` contains the character indexes, `word` is a `typedef` of `uint64_t` and `45700328 = ((((65*26+65)*26+65)*10+48)*10+48)*10+48`, which converts the characters to the correct base instead of writing `(buffer[0] - 65) * 26` etc. (It saves a few subtractions.)

I have thought of ways to improve this. One idea I had is to do use the same principle but with bit shifting rather than multiplication. I had to mix around the order of the characters to find a solution with as few operations as possible. I found that multiplication by 260 and 10 only require two shifts and an addition each, `(x << 8) + (x << 2)` and `(x << 3) + (x << 1)` respectively, and that I could use that to calculate each multiplication separately in the expression `((x2*260+x1)*260+x0)*10+(x4*260+x3)*260+x5-47366978`, where `hi = buffer[i]`. The implementation is:

```
inline word hash1(unsigned char *buffer)
{
  word y0, y1, y2, y3, y4;
  word x0 = buffer[0]; word x1 = buffer[1]; 
  word x2 = buffer[2]; word x3 = buffer[3]; 
  word x4 = buffer[4]; word x5 = buffer[5];
  y0 = (x4 << 2) + (x4 << 8) + x3;
  y1 = (y0 << 2) + (y0 << 8) + x5;
  y2 = (x2 << 2) + (x2 << 8) + x1;
  y3 = (y2 << 2) + (y2 << 8) + x0;
  y4 = (y3 << 3) + (y3 << 1) + y1;
  return y4 - 47366978;
}
```

Unfortunately, `hash2` is a little bit slower than `hash1`. This is where I run out of good ideas. I could of course try making a function that simply shifts the significant bits of each character, stacking them on top of each other, forming a 2<sup>27</sup> bit number, but that would require a 16MB vector = too large.

So, whether it be using the same principle and changing the code or using an entirely different principle, how can I make my hash function *faster* according to the requirements I mentioned in the first paragraph?

Comment: shouldn't the first be `(((((buffer[0]-'A') * 26 + (buffer[1]-'A')) * 26 + (buffer[2]-'A')) * 10 + (buffer[3]-'0')) * 10 + (buffer[4]-'0')) * 10 + (buffer[5]-'0')`?

Comment: I pre-calculated all the character subtractions to one single subtraction of 45700328, so they are equivalent in that regard.  I also need to make the `(word)` conversion so that we deal with `uint64_t` values rather than `unsigned char` values, otherwise there will be an overflow due to the large multiplications.

Comment: You could say that `a number in base 26 and 10` is more of a different representation of the data than the usual hash (since each legal string will have a different hash, and you can easily rebuild the original string from its hash). Anyway, remember that `premature optimization is the root of 90% of evil (the other 10% is caused by made-up statistics).`

Comment: if you're on x86 one suggestion is to change the base from 26 to 27 because the `lea` instruction can be used to multiply by 3, 5 or 9 very quickly

Comment: If he is on modern x86 there is nothing wrong with his hash1 function, the multiplications will be done in one instruction and it will be faster than hash2 function.

Comment: @SJuan76 Premature optimization is bad, but in this case it's justified.

Comment: @SectoKia I didn't say it's wrong. Just multiplication by 27 might be faster than multiplication by 26. Look at the dissassembly and you'll see

Comment: What is the bit width of your processor 32 or 64 or ?

Comment: @chux The bit width is 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take on the hashing problem. The approach is to use less intermediate values and more constants, to make it easy for the compiler to optimize the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t hash1(unsigned char *buffer)
{
  return
  (
    (
      (
        (
          (uint64_t)
            buffer[0] * 26
          + buffer[1]
        ) * 26
        + buffer[2]
      ) * 10
      + buffer[3]
    ) * 10
    + buffer[4]
  ) * 10
  + buffer[5]
  - 45700328;
}

uint64_t hash2(const unsigned char *buffer)
{
    uint64_t res
            = buffer[0] * 676000
            + buffer[1] * 26000
            + buffer[2] * 1000
            + buffer[3] * 100
            + buffer[4] * 10
            + buffer[5] * 1;
    return res - 45700328u;
}

int main(void)
{   
  unsigned char a, b, c, d, e, f;
  unsigned char buf[7] = { 0 }; // make it printable
  uint64_t h1, h2;


  for (a = 'A'; a <= 'Z'; a++) {
    buf[0] = a;
    for (b = 'A'; b <= 'Z'; b++) {
      buf[1] = b;
      for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
        buf[2] = c;
        for (d = '0'; d <= '9'; d++) {
          buf[3] = d;
          for (e = '0'; e <= '9'; e++) {
            buf[4] = e;
            for (f = '0'; f <= '9'; f++) {
              buf[5] = f;
              h1 = hash1(buf);
              h2 = hash2(buf);
              if (h1 != h2) {
                printf("Meh: %s mismatch: %llx %llx\n", (const char *)buf,
                  (unsigned long long)h1, (unsigned long long)h2);
                return 1;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Some simple gprofing indicates that hash2() is faster, at least most of the time. The gprof results vary a bit for each run. You may want to experiment yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried your code and indeed, it seems like your `hash2` function is slightly faster! Is there a reason why you don't `inline` the hash functions? I assumed it would speed up the execution by eliminating the function-call overhead. I guess it depends on what compiler flags you use though, as the compiler might inline the function automatically - eg, the `-finline-functions` flag in GCC.

Comment: @Max The reason I didn't inline the functions was that I wanted to be able to profile them by name. 

BTW: I have some concerns regarding the precision of the profiling data, it varies too much. Yesterday, I took a long and hard look at the assembly code for both functions, and AFAICT there's no reason for all the jitter.

Answer (score 3):

A simply method would use the 48-bit array as an integer and then *mod* by a particular number.  Can work with the raw ASCII string.  No need to subtract 26 or 10 from each character or even remove the `'\n'`.  No need for any multiplication.  Just 1 `%` operation.

```
typedef union {
  unsigned char b[8];
  uint64_t u64;
} U;

// Return a value in the range 0 to 33,541,273 which is less than 2*26*26*26*10*10*10
inline uint32_t hash3x26_mod(const unsigned char *buf) {
  static const uint32_t mod = 0X1FFCC9A;  // Determined by tests, assume little endian.
  return (uint32_t) (x->u64 % mod);
}
```

Usage

```
fgets(&U.b, sizeof U.b, istream);
// Assume U.b[7] == 0
// Assume U.b[6] == 0 or `\n`, consistently 
uint32_t perfect_AAA000_hash = hash3x26k_1(&U);
```

---

Alternatively, although OP does not want to use a wider index, the below quickly does generates a 30-bit non-colliding hash with a `*`, `>>`, and `&`

```
inline size_t hash3x26k_1(const unsigned char *buf) {
  typedef union {
    unsigned char b[6];
    uint64_t u64;
  } U;
  U *x = (U*) buf;
  uint64_t y = (x->u64 * (1ull + 16 + 16*16 + 16*16*8 + 16ull*16*8*8 + 16ull*16*8*8*8)) 
      >> 17;
  return (size_t) (y & 0x3FFFFFFF);
}
```

---

I suspect a multiplication by some TBD constant and masking with 0x01FF_FFFF would also work.

Comment: Is there are way too mathematical prove there must be a mod value that does it? Are you brute forcing it?

Comment: @SectoKia Is there are way too mathematical  proof? Likely. Are you brute forcing it?  Yes.

Comment: Keep on cranking it, this is interesting. I have a theory that the values that works well be n^2/n-1, where n is AAA000 null null.

Comment: @SectoKia  Did not see [that value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172468/creating-a-faster-perfect-hash-function-for-6-byte-strings/40181885?noredirect=1#comment67787497_40181885) as special (nor some variations on it).  I have tested the first 1/4 of the values `260*260*260` to `260*260*260*2` as well as various random values in that range. With the final `& 0x1FFFFFF` of code above, or even less restrictive `% 260u*260*260*2` values above `260*260*260*2` can also be tested

Answer (score 2):

Use 5 least significant bits of the 3 A-Z and multiple the digits into a 10 bit product: 2<sup>15 + 10</sup> < 2*17,576,000.

Expect this to be faster if `<<` is faster than `*`.  YMMV

Using a `const` pointer allows for optimizations that may not have all ready occurred.

```
inline size_t hash3x26k(const unsigned char *buf) {
  return 0x1FFFFFF
      & (((buf[0] << 20) ^ (buf[1] << 15) ^ (buf[2] << 10))
          ^ ((buf[3] * 100 + buf[4] * 10 + buf[5])));
}
```

Test code to show perfect hash and not more than 2x 26<sup>3</sup> * 10<sup>3</sup> entries needed.

```
unsigned char z[0x1FFFFFF + 1u];

int main() {
  size_t max = 0;
  unsigned char b[7] = { 0 };
  for (b[0] = 'A'; b[0] <= 'Z'; b[0]++) {
    for (b[1] = 'A'; b[1] <= 'Z'; b[1]++) {
      for (b[2] = 'A'; b[2] <= 'Z'; b[2]++) {
        for (b[3] = '0'; b[3] <= '9'; b[3]++) {
          for (b[4] = '0'; b[4] <= '9'; b[4]++) {
            for (b[5] = '0'; b[5] <= '9'; b[5]++) {
              size_t i = hash3x26k(b);
              if (i > max) max = i;
              //printf("%s %zu\n", b, i);
              if (z[i]++) {
                printf("%s %zu\n", b, i);
                exit(-1);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%zu\n", max + 1);
  return 0;
}
```

29,229,056 buckets needed.

Comment: one minor difference is that b[0] to b[2] in the OP's case lies in the range 0-25 instead of 'A'-'Z'

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Good point.  As I see it, the time and function of converting the characters into this primary range 0-25 and 0-9 is not needed and _faster_ code can start with the ASCII characters.

Comment: Clever idea! I've tried your version and compared it to Born's `hash2` function. Without optimization flags they perform about the same, but with `-Ofast` and similar Bjorn's is still faster on my 64-bit i3-3225 CPU. Have you made any comparisons?